# Stolz Cesaro type limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Given $\left\{k(a_{k+1}-a_k)\right\}_{k≥1}$ is bounded and ${\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} {\frac{a_1+a_2+....+a_n}{n}}}=a$, prove that $${\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n}=a$$
From
$\left\{k(a_{k+1}-a_k)\right\}_{k≥1}$ is bounded, I have $\{a_n\}_{n\ge1}$ is bounded since Adding all, ${\exists m,M\in \Bbb R}$ such that $$m≤{(a_{2}-a_1)}≤M$$ $$m≤{2(a_{3}-a_2)}≤M$$  $$m≤{3(a_{3}-a_2)}≤M$$ $$.........$$ $$m≤{n(a_{n+1}-a_n)}≤M$$ we have $$nm≤na_{n+1}-(a_1+a_2+....+a_n)≤nM \implies m≤a_{n+1}-{\frac{a_1+a_2+....+a_n}{n}}≤M$$ since ${\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} {\frac{a_1+a_2+....+a_n}{n}}}=a$ so
for a $${\epsilon}=1, {\exists N\in\Bbb N}$$ such that $$m+a-1≤a_{n+1}≤M+a+1$$ $\forall n≥N$ so $\{a_n\}$ is bounded. Then I stuck what next? Please can anyone help me without limsup or liminf use. Thanks in advance

Comment: Any one please without use of Limsup or Liminf??

Comment: I think that the condition should be $\lim k(a_{k+1}-a_k)=0$.

Comment: Sorry but it's not 0, yes if it was 0 then i could solve it

Comment: See Page 9, Exercise 3.14 e) in https://minds.wisconsin.edu/bitstream/handle/1793/67009/rudin%20ch%203.pdf